# Label parsing with for facet plot titles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to pass a character variable with some mathematical symbols to ggplot facet, so that the titles of the individual plots nicely display with the appropriate math symbols. Is there a nice way to get the below code to work?

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(fvar=case_when(
    drv=="f" ~ "X >=10", 
    drv=="4" ~ "0<X<=1", 
    drv=="r" ~ "1<X<10"
  ))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=displ, y=cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ fvar, labeller=label_parsed)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: Just remove `labeller=label_parsed`, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by using invisible grouping via `{}` (see `?plotmath`).

Using `{}` we can turn expressions like `0 < X <= 1` into a "valid" R like expression `{0 < X} <= 1` which can be evaluated by `label_parsed`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(fvar=case_when(
    drv=="f" ~ "X >=10", 
    drv=="4" ~ "{0<X}<=1", 
    drv=="r" ~ "{1<X}<10"
  ))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=displ, y=cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ fvar, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]